# Correct .htaccess format for Bedrock Wordpress installation?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Bedrock Wordpress website set up.

public_html has the composer,json file etc, web, vendor, config etc...

Document root is set to public_html/web

Inside that folder is the app and wp folders for Bedrock.

If you access https://wordpress-798626-3613578.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-login.php you'll see it shows but if i try logging in it just repeatedly redirects itself to the wp-login.php page.

So it seems like its using the /wp folder but at the base address but for some reason redirects over and over due to the htaccess.

My current .htaccesss looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE**

I can now access the login at
https://wordpress-798626-3613578.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-login.php and login correctly, however anywhere ive used get_site_url (wordpress function) is now https://wordpress-798626-3613578.cloudwaysapps.com/wp/my-account/my-resources (notice the /wp). site_url and home in wp_options doesnt include the /wp part. How do i get rid of the /wp part?

Many many thanks.

Comment: _"it just repeatedly redirects itself to the wp-login.php page."_ - not sure how you figured it was _redirecting_? At least with fake credentials, it simply reloads the page, because the form action is pointing to the same URL - and then tells me to speak to someone, if my school had an active membership ... So what actually happens. when you try with correct credentials?

Comment: Using the correct credentials i am redirected too https://wordpress-798626-3613578.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress-798626-3613578.cloudwaysapps.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 (the login form again)

Comment: There's already a lot of information to be found about that `reauth=1` parameter, https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+login+redirects+with+reauth%3D1+site%3Awordpress.stackexchange.com It can have multiple different reasons, try and figure out which one it is in your scenario.

Comment: Why is your htaccess actively trying to _add_ `wp/` in front of certain URLs? Can't find anything like that in https://roots.io/bedrock/docs/server-configuration/